# .htaccess rewrite rule variable with space

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have following code in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

#RewriteRule ^index$ index.php [L]

RewriteCond {REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^partners/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) partners.php?id=$1&name=$2 [NC,L]
```

when i click on link like partners/1/john it seems to work but it doesn't work with partners/1/john cena.
It seems like the link is working if there is a single word but not with 2 words and a space.

I cannot figure it out why?

Comment: _"I cannot figure it out why?"_ - because `[0-9a-zA-Z_-]` doesn't allow for a space ...?

Comment: BTW adding spaces in URL is not a good practice

Answer (score 2):

by default spaces are not matched in the regular expression pattern you've provided. To make your rule work with URLs containing spaces, you should modify your regular expression to include spaces. You can use the "\s" pattern to match spaces

```
RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite URLs that do not have a corresponding file or directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# Rewrite URLs with spaces in the name
RewriteRule ^partners/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z\s_-]+) partners.php?id=$1&name=$2 [NC,L]
```